# jQuery POST reqeust only seems to work when debugging

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

My JQuery post function doesn't seem to run unless I step by step debug through the web app. How can I cause this to trigger correctly from my onclick outside debug?

I have tried running it both in debug and outside of it, it only worked in debug.

The html that correctly passes through a value on click to the JS function below.

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="SubmitApplication('@app.JobRef')">Continue With Application</button>
```

The JS function that gets called.
The $.post is only ran on debug and I'm not sure why or how to fix it.
objApp is successfully populated from textboxes on the page.

```js
function SubmitApplication(jobref) {
    var objApp = {};
    var appID = "";

    objApp.Email = $("#email").val();
    objApp.FirstName = $("#firstname").val();
    objApp.LastName = $("#lastname").val();
    objApp.PhoneNo = $("#phoneno").val();
    objApp.Qualifications = $("#degree").val();
    objApp.DatesNotAvailForInterview = $("#datesnotavail").val();
    objApp.GdprConsent = $("#gdpr").val();
    objApp.CvFilePath = $("#uploadcv").val();
    objApp.ClFilePath = $("#uploadcl").val();
    objApp.FkJobRef = jobref;

    $.post("/Home/SubmitApplication", { objApp: objApp }, function (data) {
        if (data != null) {
            appID = data.appId;
            var modules = document.getElementsByClassName("txtboxModule");
            var results = document.getElementsByClassName("txtboxResult");
            var dates = document.getElementsByClassName("txtboxResultDate");
            var count = modules.length;

            for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                objModule = {};

                objModule.ModuleName = modules[i].value;
                objModule.Result = results[i].value;
                objModule.ResultDate = dates[i].value;
                objModule.FkAppId = appID;

                $.post("/Home/SubmitModules", { objModule: objModule }, function (data) {
                })
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("You have already applied for this position!");
            location.href = "../Details/" + jobref;
            return;
        }
    })
}
```

The method in the controller called from the post is supposed to add data to a database, this only occurs if I step through the JS.

Comment: Your button is probably part of a form? Then you need to prevent the default action of clicking that button, which is submitting the form …

Comment: It shares a div with a form but it's after the form close tag.

Comment: Check what happens in the network panel of your browser dev tools. Is there _only_ this AJAX request, or does it get quickly followed by a different one (caused by a “natural” form submission)?